# Centos - Can't start MySQL

Tags: mysql, shell, centos, innodb

I installed ioncube loader, and now i cant start my SQL Server.

Error:

```
service mysqld start
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
```

this is my log

```
150507 20:01:03 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from     /var/lib/mysql
150507 20:01:03  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
150507 20:01:03  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
150507 20:01:03  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file     operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'open'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
150507 20:01:03 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid          ended
```

This is what it shows when i try to set new perm

```
[root@server ~]# sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
chown: changing ownership of `/var/lib/mysql/notes': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `/var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `/var/lib/mysql/samp': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `/var/lib/mysql/ibdata1': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `/var/lib/mysql/mysql': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `/var/lib/mysql/shoutcast': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `/var/lib/mysql/ogp_panel': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `/var/lib/mysql/ogpbre': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `/var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1': Operation not     permitted
```

Comment: are you logged in as administrator?

Comment: Your /var partition might be mounted as read only. Try "touch /var/lib/mysql/testfile". What's the output of "df -h" and "cat /etc/mtab"?

Comment: I did all, here is the pic: http://prntscr.com/72nli8

Comment: Thanks, looks good. How about folder attributes....Can you include the output of `lsattr /var/lib/mysql/` & `ls -lha /var/lib/mysql/`

Comment: http://prntscr.com/72plen here, what now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your /var/lib/mysql/ has a `i` flag.
Run following command `chattr -i -R /var/lib/mysql` and then try `chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql`

Comment: I DID IT!! I just removed "a" flag and it works!! Thanks mate, you are the best!!

Comment: Awesome, so you had to do `chattr -ia -R /var/lib/mysql`? 
Please up-vote if you found my answer helpful :)

Comment: Yea, thanks again. I can't voteup, i need 15 rep. :/

Comment: And just to be clear, this had nothing to do with installing the ionCube Loader :) Disclosure: I am associated with ionCube.

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution can be:

`sudo chmod 755 -R /var/lib/mysql/`

Comment: try without sudo, are you sure that you are root?

Comment: I tried, and still the same thing. Yea mate, i am loggin as root, but i think i don't have full perm for all action. So, how can i see my perms?